# Keeping Form Data on Page Reload

Tags: javascript, forms, html, reload

Im currently making a website and I need a simple way to keep form data on page reloads. Is it possible to do this? I was thinking it could be done with javascript. Anyway, Please comment if you have any idea on how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: You could use JS cookies. But then you would store the data on the client computer.

Comment: Sounds similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423165/keep-form-data-on-page-refresh

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [sisyphus.js](http://simsalabim.github.com/sisyphus/) which will store form data via `localStorage` on the client and clear it on submit/reset. Simple example directly from the docuentation:

```
$('form').sisyphus();
```

Just for the record there are also other libraries/solutions available

Comment: Hmm... Not really what I need, I don't think I'll bother with this. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If this doesn't have to be client-side why not send the form up to a server occasionally for later retrieval. Something like send an ajax post with jQuery's serialize() (see http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). On the server you could retain this in memory (session state) or persist to DB if this needs to be possible for a long period of time.

A better solution might be to catch the window.onbeforeunload event, ajax the form data up to the server and then use the posted data when the form is re-retrieved from the server with the reload.

You might want to watch out however as I have noticed that some browsers already try to do this. As far as I recall FireFox will actually attempt to keep form state around, so make sure the two approaches (yours and the browser's) don't collide in some browsers.