# How to display the data in form after getting error message?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have 3 fields( name, age, mobile number) in form, and I added validation to those fields if I enter a wrong mobile number I am getting the warning message, but at the same time the page is reloading and the data what I have entered in name and age fields are showing empty input boxes.

Here I want to see the data of name and age fields after reloading the page, how can I do that.

Comment: Please share your code as well. as per my assumption, you are missing the return statement. after showing the error you have to return  not to process further

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep form data on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423165/keep-form-data-on-page-refresh)

Comment: What framework are you using if there are any?

Comment: @suguspnk I am using jinja2 templating engine with python flask frame work